# HTML CSS - input radio aligned center and vertical

Tags: html, css

[image]

As can be seen in the above image, radio are vertically aligned, but I want all radio to be center aligned in the parent div as well. I'm dynamically assigning values to the labels.

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
        <strong>Choose your username</strong><br/>
        <input type="text" maxlength="20" id="username" placeholder="Username">    

        <div id="radio_container">
        <br/><input type="radio" name="pass" id="passi1" value="pass1"><label for="passi1" id="pass1"></label>
        <br/><input type="radio" name="pass" id="passi2" value="pass2"><label for="passi2" id="pass2"></label>
        <br/><input type="radio" name="pass" id="passi3" value="pass3"><label for="passi3" id="pass3"></label>
        <br/><input type="radio" name="pass" id="passi4" value="pass4"><label for="passi4" id="pass4"></label>
        <br/><input type="radio" name="pass" id="passi5" value="pass5"><label for="passi5" id="pass5"></label>
        </div>            
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent {
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 500px;
padding: 20px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
border-radius: 10px;
font-size: 18px;                
}

#radio_container {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 200px;
text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: you can surround your radios with a div and make that div centered. and keep your text-align to the left

Comment: And you should use `label`s instead of the `span`s, so that clicking on the text selects the radio button as well …

Comment: Nice I'll add the next step in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First as I said you need to surround your radios with a div and make that div centered. and keep your text-align to the left.

you did that till now but to make your div centered, do this code instead of yours:

```
#radio_container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    text-align: left;
    display: table;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/prrd14u2/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use an unordered list for your elements instead. Seems to add a bit more control. Here's a fiddle with my [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/y68yxhmt/16/).

```
<li><input type="radio" name="pass"><span id="pass1"></span></li>
```

Also to note, you need to style the following:

```
ul {display: inline-block;}
li {text-align: left; list-style-type: none;}
```

Comment: Give some text in the spans and you'll see the problem

Comment: I would invite you to try :)

Comment: I did ;) the text then becomes center aligned, but not vertically aligned to parent

Comment: Try the link again :)

Comment: Its partially correct, but text and radio together need to be center aligned

Comment: The answer you chose did the exact same as mine... If you click my link again, you'll see I had updated it after your original feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vz9ftwhL/1/) set margin-left as per requirment :

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
        <strong>Choose your username</strong><br/>
        <input type="text" maxlength="20" id="username" placeholder="Username">    

        <br/><strong>Choose an option</strong>
        <div id="radio-button"><input type="radio" name="pass"><span id="pass1"></span>
        <br/><input type="radio" name="pass"><span id="pass2"></span>
        <br/><input type="radio" name="pass"><span id="pass3"></span>
        <br/><input type="radio" name="pass"><span id="pass4">jhvjrwr</span>
        <br/><input type="radio" name="pass"><span id="pass5">sw</span>
            </div>

    </div>
```

css:

```
#parent {
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 500px;
padding: 20px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
border-radius: 10px;
font-size: 18px;                
}
#radio-button{
  text-align :left; 
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: 40%;
}
```

Comment: that would NOT be center aligning perfectly, try variable length text, it does not give correct result